# Sending an email using a php contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

i am trying to create a contact form using php. When i click send the email appears to have sent but the recipient never actually receives it. Maybe i need to set up an SMTP server but i am unsure how to do this. Thanks in advance

in the form.html i have

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">

<p>Request Phone Call:</p>
Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call"><br />
No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call"><br />

<p>Website</p> <input type="text" name="website">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Website Update</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Information Addition</option>
<option value="new">New Products</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

in the mail.php file i have

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n        Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "kerrip90@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-    decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you post 1) your php mail configuration in [php.ini(http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) 2) log entries generated by your mail/MTA server?

Answer (score 1):

For the `mail()` function to work you can simply just install postfix on your server by issuing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `pear` package.

```
sudo apt-get install pear
sudo pear install mail
```

The installation will recommend few other packages too.Install them in the same way.To send the mail use:

```
public function sendMail($to)
  {
     require_once('Mail.php');
     $this->_to=$to;
     $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
     $port = "465";
     $headers = array ('From' => $this->_from,
                   'To' => $this->_to,
                   'Subject' => $this->_subject);
     $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                          array ('host' => $host,
                                 'port' => $port,
                                 'auth' => true,
                                 'username' => $this->_username,
                                 'password' => $this->_password));
    $mail = $smtp->send($this->_to, $headers, $this->_body);
 }
```